# How to find the angle shown in figure?

Tags: trigonometry

The triangle shown in figure [image]

I have to calculate the angle $\theta.$ I calculate the angles $135^o$ and $15^o.$ Also tried to use law of sine. but don't know how to find the angle $\theta.$

Comment: Set the length of the bottom edge to be 2 (each part is 1). You can now calculate all edges of the left triangle. Now you have 2 edge lengths and an angle of the right triangle and therefore you can calculate the rest using the law of cosines.

Comment: It might be possible to do this with pure geometry, but don't take my word for it. If you draw a line from the $30º$ angle so that it is split into $15º$ and $15º$, you have now bisected it (angle bisector theorem) and created an isosceles triangle. If $\theta$ is a nice value, it strongly hints at a purely geometric method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: triangle angle problem]

I managed to obtain a synthetic solution. This is my first time posting a solution, so let me now if I do something wrong.

The idea I followed is to create isosceles and equilateral triangles until I used all the information given in the question. I first split the 135 degree angle into 120 and 15 degrees. In the newly created quadrilateral, I connected the diagonals. Finally, I marked equal sides until obtaining the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there'a a better and faster way, but this is how I'd solve it

Describe the oblique sides of the left triangle by the straight lines on which they sit, (and let the length of the horizontal side be $1$) i.e., $y=\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}$ and $y=x-1$ (because $\tan 30º=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ and $\tan 45º=1$). The vertices of this triangle are located at $(0,0),(1,0)$ and $(\frac{1}{2}\left(3+\sqrt{3}\right),\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)).$

The rightmost side of the triangle to the right lies on the same line as $(2,0)$ and $(\frac{1}{2}\left(3+\sqrt{3}\right),\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)).$ This line has slope $2+\sqrt{3}$ and corresponds to an angle of $75º$. Therefore $\theta=105º$.

Comment: $105°$ maybe?  Typo?

Comment: I corrected it, thanks @OscarLanzi

Comment: All good now, as can be seen by the answer score.